# python requests sometime throws SNI error for IPv6 address only

Tags: python-requests, ipv6, sni

I am using **python requests** package for communication, while making **GET/POST** query **using IPv6 address it fails** on some server and throws **SNI error**. Here weird thing is on some similar environment it works fine. **It works always fine with IPv4 addresses.** My doubt where is how to start with such problem.

Error: Hostname  provided via SNI and hostname  provided via HTTP are different

Comment: Can you post some code? Maybe a stack trace? Maybe some context? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: As said before, please post some code.